# Feed back problem on FM Radio after new 100 amp box installed

Tags: electrical-panel

I installed a 100 amp box from my exsting 200 amp box. I seem to be getting feed back from my FM radio when I plug in a battery charger and turn it on. Other items don't seem to effect the radio. Did I do something wrong with my installation? I have put in a ground fault outlet as my first in line and I have installed switched overhead LED lights. There is only one 20amp circuit at this time. The two boxes are in the same building, about 50ft apart in an addition. When I use the charger in the original part of the building, I don't have any feedback or buzzing. When I turn on the new lights there is no problem with the radio. I only have one circuit with one outlet (GFI) and then to a switch that turns on my overhead LED lights. I have plugged in other lights in the outlet an no interference.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Please take our [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Tell us a lot more about your installation. Obviously yes, something about thqt caused it.  But if you want our help, we'll need more than this.  You can [edit] in details.

Comment: Is feedback what your really mean?  For feed back to occur, you need a speaker AND a microphone.   Or are you talking about static, buzzing or a 60 hz hum?

Comment: Can your radio run on battery power? If so, please let us know if you get the same noise from it when it's not plugged into the power outlet, but the battery charger is.

Comment: I'm concerned that this is a "canary in the coal mine" for a much more serious problem with the panel installation.  70% chance it'll be an easy fix; best to look at it IMO.

Comment: Did you run 4 wires (hot, hot, neutral, ground) for the feeder? DId you make sure the Z-strap or green bonding screw was *omitted* from the subpanel? DId you make sure that all the neutrals went on the neutral bar and all the grounds went on the ground bar?

Answer (score 1):

Many small power supplies emit high frequency signals into the air or power line. Also LED bulbs have those issues. Sometimes turning the plug, helps - e.g. in case of schuko or Euro plugs. This can't be done with outlet systems  where the hot line has to be at a  fixed position.

Sometimes it helps to rotate the receiver by 90 degree. What nearly always helps is to enlarge the distance resp. to connect the loader and receiver to different circuits far from each other. 
Also different positioning or grounding of the antenna might help.

The grounding wiring of the complete house/Appartment should be done in star form. Earthing/Ground Loops could easily catch any signals which then enter the ground of the receiver electronic.

Answer (score 0):

If it were a design or grounding problem inside of the charger, the problem would exist wherever it was plugged in. Given that the charger does not cause the problem when plugged in elsewhere, it points to a poor ground connection at the outlet you are concerned about. With a poor ground connection at the receptacle, relatively "normal" electrical noise (caused by the way the charger works) will travel on the conductors, which then act like radio antennae.

Comment: Since this is connected to a new panel installation,  it seems likely the grounding issue may pertain to the panel.  This could be urgent!